# Долгие команды в докере

Tags: docker, cmd

Вообщем есть такая проблема, я себе в проекте который работает на docker написал скриптовый файлик который качает плагины через composer, выглядит примерно так:

```
docker exec -ti php sh -c "cd var/www/project/apps/tele2 && composer install"
```

Вообщем то ничего сложного заходим в контейнер тащимся до нужной папки и качаем всё что указано. Сама проблема заключается в том, что библиотек очень много и через какой-то промежуток времени я ловлю ошибку. Однако если делать всё это руками, то никакой ошибки нет и всё скачивается хорошо. Как можно решить такую страную проблему??

Выглядит ошибка так:

```
- Installing vlucas/phpdotenv (v2.6.9): Extracting archive
- Installing opis/closure (3.6.2): Extracting archive
- Installing yiisoft/yii2-debug (2.1.18): Extracting archive
- Installing phpspec/php-diff (v1.1.3): Extracting archive
- Installing yiisoft/yii2-gii (2.2.3): Extracting archive
37/75 [=============>--------------]  49%    Install of bower-asset/font-awesome failed
Install of mpdf/mpdf failed
Install of bower-asset/jquery-ui failed
Install of bower-asset/bootstrap failed
Install of phpoffice/phpspreadsheet failed
Install of goodby/csv failed
Install of imagine/imagine failed
Install of bower-asset/sweetalert failed
Install of symfony/process failed
The following exception is caused by a process timeout
Check https://getcomposer.org/doc/06-config.md#process-timeout for details

In Process.php line 1204:
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
The process "'/usr/bin/unzip' -qq '/var/www/project/apps/tele2/app/vendor/composer/tmp-a8ffef473a25eb18ded9c8fc075e9091' -d '/var/www/project/apps/tele2/app/vendor/composer/b231a75c'" exceeded the timeout of 300 seconds.          
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    

install [--prefer-source] [--prefer-dist] [--prefer-install PREFER-INSTALL] [--dry-run] [--dev] [--no-suggest] [--no-dev] [--no-autoloader] [--no-progress] [--no-install] [-v|vv|vvv|--verbose] [-o|--optimize-autoloader] [-a|--classmap-authoritative] [--apcu-autoloader] [--apcu-autoloader-prefix APCU-AUTOLOADER-PREFIX] [--ignore-platform-req IGNORE-PLATFORM-REQ] [--ignore-platform-reqs] [--] [<packages>...]
```

Comment: Ну для начала прочитать текст ошибки, наверное?

Comment: @andreymal В описание добавил текст ошибки

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Советую поправить php.ini в контейнере, выставить таймауты побольше.

Comment: Но если запускать напрямую то всё хорошо и ни одной ошибки. Только если через скрипт cmd